# Validation rules check

Tags: validation-rule

I need a help in creating validation rule, I need to throw validation message if a checkbox is checked and corresponding comment is not provided and there are around 10 different checkboxes.

```
AND(
    OR(cm_IsChange_check__c = True, ISBLANK(cm_IsChange_text__c)),
    OR(cm_Income_check__c = True, ISBLANK(cm_Income_text__c)),
    OR(cm_IsSubstitute_check__c = True, ISBLANK(cm_IsSubstitute_text__c))
)
```

So I need to show the validation error message if IsChange checkbox is checked and user has not provided any comments then throw validation, and so on.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point out a specific part that you're stuck on.

Comment: Without knowing the data types of these fields, it is difficult to say if `Validation Rule` is even the correct tool for the job. If any of the comment fields are Long Text Area or Rich Text Area, you will need `Apex` instead.

Comment: The comment is text field, and if I use this,AND(cm_IsChange_check__c = True, ISBLANK(cm_IsChange_text__c)), it works but if I try to implement the same thing with other different check boxes it's not working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this -

```
OR(
    AND(Checkbox1, ISBLANK(Textfield1)),
    AND(Checkbox2, ISBLANK(Textfield2)),
    AND(Checkbox3, ISBLANK(Textfield3)),
)
```

The problem with your validation is that you are using AND condition outer side and if any pair condition is false then the output will be false.